# ImportError: No module named pxssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh

I am trying to use `pxssh` module to make SSH connection to the client - however I am getting:

```
ImportError: No module named pxssh
```

I found this file in Python installation so I would guess that's correct:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py
```

I am of course running my app with Python 2.7 and I've even tried to import `pexpect`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you try `from pexpect import pxssh`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, try `from pexpect import pxssh`.

update:

---

The solution only works for Linux as `pxssh` is not supported on Windows

Answer (score 8):

If the problem is not resolved by the earlier suggestion:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
```

The pexpect library might be outdated, so run:

```
 sudo pip install pexpect --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

If /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py exists, then use the below command

> python2.7 'yourprogram.py'

as python command is not linked to 2.7 version. Please check python -V to get the version.