# No module named PXSSH

Tags: python-2.7

I am just a beginner using python 2.7 . Please forgive my naive- ness

my following code is not working

```
import sys
import os
import time
import re
import pxssh

a = ['192.168.50.11', '192.168.50.12']

for i in a:
    Host  = i
    print Host
    User = "xyz"
    Password = "abc"
    tn = pxssh.pxssh(Host)
    tn.read_until("login as: ")
    tn.write(User + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(Password + "\n")
    tn.read_until("#")
    tn.write("show run\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    output = tn.read_all()
    time.sleep(3)
    f = open("C:/Python27/file/"+ Host + ".txt", "w+")
    f.write(output)
    f.close()
    tn.close()
```

it gives me following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/backup_config_files", line 5, in <module>
    import pxssh
ImportError: No module named pxssh
```

Please let me know how can i resolve this pxssh module issue with python 2.7 in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install pexpect using

```
pip install pexpect
```

Then import using

```
from pexpect import pxssh
```

Refs: [docs](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html)

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883912/importerror-no-module-named-pxssh).

`pxssh` is a class, that you must import **from** the module `pexpect`.

Your import would look like:

```
from some.location.pexpect import pxssh
```

If you do not have the `pexpect` module, `pip install pexpect` in bash in your working environment.